Scroll View doesn't Scroll with a parallel Scroll View
I'm learning React Native and need help understanding how multiple scrollViews interact with each other.
I have my primary screen where there is a primary View where there is a scrollview (the exercise cards) which works perfectly as expected. The problem is when I push the filter button, a box with a scrollView appears, but I'm unable to scroll.
I purposefully disabled the scrolling ability of the primary scrollView (exercise cards), and when I took this out it didnt' fix my problem.
I've seen other places where it says to permit nested scrollView, set it to true, but that didn't work either. I assume that this didn't work because they are not nested.
I also realize I could make it a modal and it would alleviate my issue, but I'm more curious now why this doesn't work and how to get it to work.
Primary Screen with my primary scrollView:
<View
        style={Styles.background}>
        {addExerciseModalOpen &&
            <AddExerciseModal setAddExerciseModalOpen={setAddExerciseModalOpen} setExercises={setExerciseList}
                              exercises={exerciseList}/>}
        <View style={{position: 'absolute', right: '6%', bottom: '14%', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
            {filterModalOpen &&
                <FilterModal selectedFilter={selectedFilter} setSelectedFilter={setSelectedFilter} />}
        </View>
        <View
            style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center'}}
        >
            <View
                style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                    alignItems: 'center'
                }}
            >
                <Text style={Styles.titleText}>Your Exercises :</Text>
                <WhiteDivider dividerWidth={100}/>
            </View>
            <ScrollView
                nestedScrollEnabled={true}
                scrollEnabled={!filterModalOpen}

                style={{width:'90%', height: '100%'}}>
            {
                exerciseList.map(exercise => {
                    return (
                        <ExerciseCard key={exercise.exerciseName} exercise={exercise}/>
                    )
                })
            }</ScrollView>
        </View>
        <View
            style={{position: 'absolute', right: '6%', bottom: '8%', alignItems: 'flex-end', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Pressable
                style={{paddingRight: 35}}
                onPress={() => {
                    Haptics.notificationAsync(
                        Haptics.NotificationFeedbackType.Success
                    )
                    setAddExerciseModalOpen(false)
                    setFilterModalOpen(!filterModalOpen);
                }}
            >
                <Octicons name="filter" size={40} color={Colors.darkMode.button}/>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable
                onPress={() => {
                    Haptics.notificationAsync(
                        Haptics.NotificationFeedbackType.Success
                    )
                    setFilterModalOpen(false)
                    setAddExerciseModalOpen(!addExerciseModalOpen);

                }}
            >
                <Ionicons name="add-circle-outline" size={40} color={Colors.darkMode.button}/>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    </View>

Filter Modal, contains secondary scrollView:
<View style={{
        zIndex: 1000,
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: 125,
        height: 150,
        borderRadius: 25,
        backgroundColor: Colors.darkMode.cards1
    }}>
        <ScrollView
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            style={{
                marginTop: 15,
                marginBottom: 15
            }}>
            {renderFilterChoices()}
        </ScrollView>
    </View>


